# tab and Shift+tab key event in KendoGird

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid

I am using KendoUI tool for UI for the application in which i have a grid of 2 Columns and 3 rows  i mean 6 cells and all these cells having input type text.I want that when moving from one cell to other i.e textboxes using "tab" key it must throw me any event say as alert("I am in Cell").
Here my Code as Follows that is not working please suggest me  on this.

```
$(function () {
$("input[type=text]").keyup(function (e) {
                var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
                if (keyCode == 9) {
                    alert("I am in Cell")
                    grid.closeCell();
                }

            });
});
```

Comment: It's working http://jsfiddle.net/fE5YR/

Comment: yes but not in my case as i am using KendoGrid

Answer (score 0):

For tab key you have to add keydown() function.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#KendoGridName").keydown(function(e){

var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
                if (keyCode == 9) {
                    alert("I am in Cell")
                    e.preventDefault(); 
                }
});

});

</script>
```

e.preventDefault() function prevents the default behaviour of the tab key i.e. to go to next active control and hence user is moved from one cell to another in grid.